# Bootstrap not working for Rails 4.2.4 application in development

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a brand new to Ruby on Rails (I come from a .NET background), so bear with me if I don't explain something well enough or I don't include all the needed information.

So I'm building this new Rails app, I installed the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem, did `rails g bootstrap:install`, got everything created, and now I'm just trying to start modifying on of the views. The problem is nothing from Bootstrap is being recognized.

Here is what my application.html.erb looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: 'all' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span9"><%= yield %></div>
        <div class="span3">
            <h2>About Us</h2>
            Test text.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.20'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

And just an FYI, I have an assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less file.

So my problem, again, is that none of the Bootstrap CSS in my application.html.erb is being recognized. I also have a home page that only contains text, which is being displayed but not formatted properly with the "About Us" from the application.html.erb.

Here is the stylesheets/js included (from the source):

```
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/home.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-e80e8f2318043e8af94dddc2adad5a4f09739a8ebb323b3ab31cd71d45fd9113.css?body=1" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery.self-a714331225dda820228db323939889f149aec0127aeb06255646b616ba1ca419.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-d456baa54c1fa6be2ec3711f0a72ddf7a5b2f34a6b4f515f33767d6207b7d4b3.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/transition.self-db278e3a8fa6249c16796b113ebd29e11ef4e2cd021618ed84895d524a4511e0.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/alert.self-ebce91ec66c71bcee451ea7da9128fd1bf8faa02c6d22ea04c598423431e4c08.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/modal.self-ab1767545e27c0dbd36971e656ae4927171f673e3d932cdec2cbef39e991952b.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/dropdown.self-8bb9309b6c24a4ba6b94026a049d25b13bdc0553b6fe83255c14a715ba624cc4.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/scrollspy.self-bd0c6724cdc75302fe98dfeff923112b76c1673cf4a0752a7050b7feea15594c.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/tab.self-7e3ee4a243bb416b5f0111a0be08f8547c5d72ba71fe4afe4a4a007f5cb4e10e.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/tooltip.self-d7f9330825307d053f68da11bb9ddc9b070df72deef3d115f2f3d55f66b17457.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/popover.self-cd672ecad3b549e1dbd89bfd044e5812d6fdade56f42d48e3acee0c3f4614526.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/button.self-ceb562de883e04359bb2c06f07bdf6ecf065cc8a5027e2e58857c5e91b0b68e3.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/collapse.self-a87553101c955a01e2e8c81fad69a16582ddbf58fe95d5eb335dde5567af7647.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/carousel.self-5d09995e01b647168888180d40e271f9a6759d68ae7ac029d7026af58813d376.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/affix.self-14e04bbe71282aa039322ab93e3a3a886ddede5f59a2f365f7c861f697bbeb21.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap.self-fbfa5ad7d9aa0afe439ec4ff3883acc4cb92b62cb67c40d674320c9aa1d4642d.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-6fb86ff58d930b560704818c7d9e5f60d83d65b91c6778c7f7e4210d5ba82127.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.self-fdc98dee79ee88255e10cac6caa91338165cb76cf0d263744d8d90011fc2ef8f.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/home.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-f8806224e027f3e3f0138ea9ce99319e298dfdb323304d1f1be6eae8e8c74724.js?body=1"></script>
  <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="Ty+Ax9V57UdwKpxEvS0+AubRWPpLN2m4bOgBPAFBFu5FXDGxcrTpulbWxAAROqczhy+cpckq7ltR9Tya91TC4g==" />
</head>
```

If there is any other information that I need to provide to help debug this, let me know and I'll be happy to provide it.

**Edit**
Here is my application.css file:

```
*= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap_and_overrides
```

Comment: show your application.css file

Comment: If you didn't use gem less css. you can use `rails generate bootstrap:install static`. For more information https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails

Comment: I used `rails g bootstrap:install less`, like guide said to do.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks like it was set up correctly, but note that `twitter-bootstrap-rails` is packaged with Bootstrap 3.2.

The `.span9` and `.span3` classes are deprecated after Bootstrap `2.X`. Try this instead:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-9"><%= yield %></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <h2>About Us</h2>
            Test text.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check out the reference for [grids in Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Comment: Thanks for the input! For my original problem, I found my issue. I was doing a "less" install of bootstrap, but didn't have the required gems in my Gemfile (therubyracer, less-rails).  The reason I didn't put those in is because they currently are not compatible with Windows. When I just do a normal install (not less), it works fine.  So I'm creating a VM now and am just going to do my development there instead.

Comment: Good to hear that you found the issue @Blake. A VM sounds like a good idea. Another option worth looking into might be a cloud based environment, like Cloud9 or Nitrous.io.